# Convert automatically all forms to Grails Fields Plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

With Grails Fields Plugin you can write an actually shorter, cleaner, DRY code:

```
<bean:withBean beanName="person">
    <bean:field property="username" label="Login Name:"/>
    <bean:field property="userRealName" label="Full Name:"/>    >
</bean:withBean>
```

The code above would do the same than the following:

```
<tr class="prop">
  <td valign="top" class="name"><label for="username">Login Name:</label></td>
  <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: person, field: 'username', 'errors')}">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="${person.username?.encodeAsHTML()}"/>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr class="prop">
  <td valign="top" class="name"><label for="userRealName">Full Name:</label></td>
  <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: person, field: 'userRealName', 'errors')}">
    <input type="text" id="userRealName" name="userRealName" value="${person.userRealName?.encodeAsHTML()}"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**But, must I change all my already written code manually?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails fields plugin have [an option for scaffolding](http://freeside.co/grails-fields/guide/scaffolding.html), so at least you can regenerate your scaffolded code.

I agree with @dmahapatro about the consistency of the code, if you choose to use the plugin, it's an effort that must be made, to make all your views have the same pattern.

Comment: +1 Thanks again mate, bringing this up. You won't believe, I was thinking of editing my answer to add the above point midst my chores. I guess I have to increase my # of beers to be proactive. :P

Comment: I forgot something important: thanks to you and @dmahapatro! :)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would have stuck to one word

> **CONSISTENCY**

I would rather convert all of them using the plugin or do not use the plugin and convert none. So that in future, I would not have to deal with two types of handling. On the other hand, if you have a lot of views to be converted and you have a short deadline, then I would add this task to my backlog.

But again, it differs from person to person. This was my opinion. I hope this could be useful.